# Provisioning error with Vagrant, Chef and a veewee box

Tags: deployment, rubygems, chef-infra, vagrant

I'm trying to build an *Ubuntu 12.04.2 amd64 precise* box with **PHP**.
Looking around I found this repository that I'd like to use as [starting point](https://github.com/simshaun/symfony-vagrant), trying it everything works fine, but I need to change the base box with a 64bit one.

So, I created a new box using [veewee](https://github.com/jedi4ever/veewee):

```
veewee vbox define 'web-php54-precise' 'ubuntu-12.04.2-server-amd64'
veewee vbox build 'web-php54-precise'
veewee vbox export 'web-php54-precise'
```

Cloning source repository:

```
git clone --recursive git://github.com/simshaun/symfony-vagrant.git
cd symfony-vagrant/vagrant
```

I changed lines in the `Vagrantfile`, in order to user my new box:

```
config.vm.box = "web-php54-precise"
config.vm.box_url = ""
```

But running `vagrant up` I get a fatal error during **chef-solo** deploy.
I tried to change `require_recipe` in `include_recipe` without success. I think that the provisioner doesn't recognize the file `networking_basic/attributes/default.rb` and so `node['networking']['packages']` results undefined.

Note that adding the same recipe directly into *Vagrantfile* works fine:

```
config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
    chef.cookbooks_path = "cookbooks"
    # chef.add_recipe "networking_basic" <= this works
    chef.add_recipe "vagrant_main"
    # cut #
end
```

Did I miss something configuring the base box with veewee?
**Some ideas?** Thanks.

Here is the log:

```
  vagrant git:(master) ✗ vagrant up
[default] Importing base box 'web-php54-precise'...
[default] Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
[default] Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
[default] Forwarding ports...
[default] -- 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
[default] -- 80 => 8080 (adapter 1)
[default] Creating shared folders metadata...
[default] Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
[default] Available bridged network interfaces:
1) en0: Ethernet
2) en1: Wi-Fi (AirPort)
3) p2p0
What interface should the network bridge to? 1
[default] Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
[default] Booting VM...
[default] Waiting for VM to boot. This can take a few minutes.
[default] VM booted and ready for use!
[default] Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
[default] Mounting shared folders...
[default] -- v-root: /vagrant
[default] -- project1: /home/vagrant/web-app
[default] -- v-csc-1: /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks
[default] Running provisioner: Vagrant::Provisioners::ChefSolo...
[default] Generating chef JSON and uploading...
[default] Running chef-solo...
stdin: is not a tty
[2013-02-22T13:10:02+00:00] INFO: *** Chef 11.4.0 ***
[2013-02-22T13:10:03+00:00] INFO: Setting the run_list to ["recipe[vagrant_main]"] from JSON
[2013-02-22T13:10:03+00:00] INFO: Run List is [recipe[vagrant_main]]
[2013-02-22T13:10:03+00:00] INFO: Run List expands to [vagrant_main]
[2013-02-22T13:10:03+00:00] INFO: Starting Chef Run for web-php54-precise
[2013-02-22T13:10:03+00:00] INFO: Running start handlers
[2013-02-22T13:10:03+00:00] INFO: Start handlers complete.
[2013-02-22T13:10:03+00:00] WARN: require_recipe is deprecated and will be removed in a future release, please use include_recipe
[2013-02-22T13:10:03+00:00] WARN: require_recipe is deprecated and will be removed in a future release, please use include_recipe


================================================================================

Recipe Compile Error in /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/vagrant_main/recipes/default.rb

================================================================================




NoMethodError

-------------

undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass




Cookbook Trace:
---------------
  /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/networking_basic/recipes/default.rb:7:in `from_file'
  /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/vagrant_main/recipes/default.rb:10:in `from_file'


Relevant File Content:
----------------------
/tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/networking_basic/recipes/default.rb:

  1:  #
  2:  # Cookbook Name:: networking_basic
  3:  # Recipe:: default
  4:  #
  5:  #
  6:
  7>> node['networking']['packages'].each do |netpkg|
  8:    package netpkg
  9:  end
 10:


[2013-02-22T13:10:03+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[2013-02-22T13:10:03+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2013-02-22T13:10:03+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-stacktrace.out
[2013-02-22T13:10:03+00:00] FATAL: NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
Chef never successfully completed! Any errors should be visible in the
output above. Please fix your recipes so that they properly complete.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption was correct, node['networking'] was nil, so it couldn't have the ['packages'] sub-attribute.

The underlying problem is that the vagrant_main cookbook is doing "include_recipe", but the networking_basic cookbook's attributes file, where node['networking']['packages'] is defined, wasn't loaded yet.

In Chef versions 10 and earlier, Chef didn't [load cookbook components in a deterministic order](http://tickets.opscode.com/browse/CHEF-2903). The general assumption is run list order, since that's the order recipes are loaded. So Chef now does that as of version 11.

However, in this case the run list doesn't have the networking_basic cookbook, the vagrant_main includes it. In order to make sure that the components are loaded, dependencies on the cookbooks we're using is required. To resolve this issue, create a vagrant_main/metadata.rb file with the following content:

```
name "vagrant_main"
depends "apache2"
depends "apt"
depends "mysql"
depends "networking_basic"
depends "php"
depends "xdebug"
```

Comment: Excellent answer. After searching for hours this actually worked.